# TN3 Plugin Not Working Under IIS / WebMatrix

Tags: plugins, iis

Has anybody been able to get the TN3 Plugin running under Windows IIS?

I'm also having trouble viewing anytype of logs to see whats happening. It installs/activates successfully. It also successfully uploads images but it doesn't show the images in the image selector view.

Error Screen Shot: https://s3.amazonaws.com/satisfaction-production/s3_images/705730/Capture.PNG?1330552614

Issue tracker I made: https://getsatisfaction.com/tn3gallery/topics/tn3_gallery_not_working_under_windows_iis_webmatrix

Plugin Site: http://www.tn3gallery.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your screenshot, the plugin has some basic code errors and you run your installation with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. Turn the debug mode and other ways for error reporting off and see if it works now. If it doesn’t, use another plugin or wait for the developer to fix it.

Comment: I turned the debug on so I could see the error it was generating. So it was intentional.